# Cannot write to resource file while running on docker

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker

I need to update the properties file inside the resource folder. But it throws no such file or Directory exception while running on docker, but it works outside the docker in springboot. Please can any one help me to out of this issue. This want to achieve in post construct.

**some trace**

```
Error occured. Cause : file:/my-translation-service.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/translator/definitions/translations_en.properties (No such file or directory)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/my-translation-service.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/translator/definitions/translations_en.properties (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
```

Comment: You're trying to write into a file that is packaged into a jar. That won't work ever, run in Docker or not. You'll need to unpack it if you do want to write into it.

Comment: This might work if you run the code inside your IDE, since in that case the path to the file does not point to a jar but rather a folder on your local hard disk. But as @daniu pointed out, this should not work when the application has been packaged regardless of whether you use Docker or not.

Comment: @tom1299, yes its working while I run from Eclipse. So what can I do, I want to update the file during the application initialize.

Comment: https://github.com/ipa-rar/gRPC-ros-interface-generator/issues/1